# Deep recursion memory leak - unset a fopen resource?

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, recursion

I have a recursive function to iterate over 11M database records, 1000 at a time. As it approached 9M it stopped. My assumption of a memory problem was confirmed when I displayed `get_memory_usage()` after every 1000 records.

The function works something like this:

```
<?
get_data_block();

function get_data_block($id=0);
{
    //open a csv file for writing
    $packages_sorted_csv=fopen("./csv/packages_sorted.csv", "a");

    //get 1000 records and process them
    //$unsorted = array of 1000 records from database
    foreach($unsorted as $row);
    {
        $ct++;
        $id++;
        //$packages_sorted = array of processed data

        //write output
        fputcsv($packages_sorted_csv, $packages_sorted);
    }
    fclose($packages_sorted_csv);

    if($ct==1000)
    {
        unset($unsorted);
        echo 'Mem usage: '.memory_get_usage();
        get_data_block($id);    //call the function again
    }else{
        //finished
    }
}

?>
```

Does anyone have a tip about how to release all resources with recursive functions?
...or is there a way to call the same function again so it's not called by itself?

Notes:

- I have to chunk the data in blocks to free up the busy mysql server.
- I have tried unsetting every defined variable that's not in the global scope.
- The only thing I can't seem to unset is the fopen resource.
- The memory size grows by about 400k each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, recursion doesn't seem like the right approach.

Build a second function and rearrange that one so that you can do something like (pseudo-code):

```
while (!$done) {
  $id = get_data_block($id);
  $done = // determine if finished or not
}
```

i.e. return `$id` from `get_data_block`, giving it an invalid value if no more processing needs to be done. You won't have to worry about the stack frames piling up this way.

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thanks so much. Sometimes I just can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

A good programming language should recognize tail recursion and turn it into an implicit loop.

PHP apparently doesn't, so at some point you'll get a stack overflow. Try rewriting your code to use a loop instead, or e.g. a processing queue to iterate over.